# Logically Layout Multiple Items into a View by their X and Y coordinates

Tags: objective-c, layout, cgpoint

I have a `UIView` and I want to add a series of programmatically generated `UIButtons` to it.

I've created a method that places each button (of standard size) via a `CGPoint`.

I want to lay these buttons out 3 in a row, over as many rows as needed.

I've no idea how to go about programatically generating the x and y coordinates to place the items on the view. I'm stuck on how to get the buttons to drop onto a new row once three have been placed.

Here's my code, I want to process something in this method to return the coordinates based only upon the index of the button:

```
- (CGPoint)calculateCoordinatesWithIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    NSInteger x = 100;
    NSInteger y = 50;
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

The only solutions I can think of seem really clunky and inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello what about something like :

```
#define BUTTON_WIDTH    100
#define BUTTON_HEIGHT   50
- (void) placeButtonsFromButtonsArray:(NSArray *) buttons{

   CGFloat currentXPosition = 0.0;
   CGFloat currentYPosition = 0.0;

   for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [buttons count]; i++){
        b.frame = CGRectMake(currentXPosition, currentYPosition, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        if (i%3 == 2){
           currentXPosition = 0;
           currentYPostion += BUTTON_HEIGHT;
        }
        else currentXPosition += BUTTON_WIDTH;
   }
}
```

or Using your method :

```
  - (CGPoint)calculateCoordinatesWithIndex:(NSInteger)index{

     //computes on which line the button should be
     NSUInteger line = (index/3);

     //computes on which row the button should be 
     NSUInteger row = (index%3) ;     

     return CGPointMake(row*BUTTON_WIDTH, line*BUTTON_HEIGHT);
}
```

Comment: The line/row function that you included is Mint. Thanks mate!

Comment: Just added 8 random options to test the functionality - problem is that they appear to be randomly placed. 6 first, then 1, then 2, then 5, then 4, then 3

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I'm an idiot. All buttons are stored in a dictionary... unsorted :( Your answer is completely valid. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that if you do :
>      NSMutableArray * arrayOfLabel = [NSMutableArray new];
>      for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<8; i++){
>         UILabel * l = [UILabel new];
>         l.text = [NSString stringWithInteger:i];
>         [arrayOfLabels addObject:l];
>         [self.view addSubview:l];
>         [l release];
>      }

an the use you placing method to the array you'll have something like 
>     6   1   2 
>     5   4   3 
>     7   8 
?

Comment: No, it was my mistake not yours. Sorry for the confusion - just forget I ever said anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 6, you could use a UICollectionView for this.

Comment: FWIW out of context. It may be painful as collectionView uses reusable cells and buttons' targets may be hard to set.
To compare with HTML development, using a collectionView is like using tables. It can do quite everything but it's expensive.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
    in  .h

```
  {

NSInteger x;

 NSInteger y;

 int noOfbtninrow;

 }

  -(void)viewDidload

{


x = 100;

y = 50;

 noOfbtninrow=0;
 }

- (CGPoint)calculateCoordinatesWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
 {
   if(noOfbtninrow==3)

 {
  x=100;
   y=y+100
 noOfbtninrow=0;
  }

  else

 {
  noOfbtninrow++;
   x=x+100;
  }
  return CGPointMake(x, y);
  }
```